# Others free deployment project for .NET applications

Tags: .net, deployment

Setup project with Visual studio 2008 really sucks. Do you know if there is other free alternatives ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it sucks. It is rather basic though, but still a good tool for simple application setups. It all depends what you want to do with your setup. You should carefully consider whether you need the power of e.g. WiX, as the price is also higher complexity and a steep lerning curve. Each tool for its intended purpose ;-)

Comment: setup project in vs2008 can't be built without VS, and passing arguments to custom actions during deployment is a pain. I've spent to much time on stupid things with this tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Windows Installer XML](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

It will be available as part of Visual Studio 2010 and it is very powerful in term of flexibility, although it lack a UI designer (for those who prefer that).

Answer (score 5):

[Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php) - Very flexible, yet simple.

Comment: I'll second that.  You can do a lot with it.  Plus, you get to write a little Pascal (blasted := and no semicolon before and else!) ;-)  Seriously, it is definitely worth checking out.  There's a good amount of examples and, as Christopher has stated, it is flexible.  Coolest thing for me - calling external DLLs to address application-specific steps during install.

Comment: +1 I've used this thing since it's conception. Very easy to script.

Answer (score 3):

There also these two:

- [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- [Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

There is a big of a limitation with NSIS, where you can't easily install to the GAC.